# Selecting a table data using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i am new to javascript and jquery.I just like to know if there is any way of selecting a table data using this format:

```
$("#myTable").row[index1][index2];
```

where index1 is row index, index2 is column. Anything similar is fine too.

Comment: what is your html code for your tables?  Does your row and column have identifiers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this : you can use [.eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) in jQuery to traverse through `tr` and `td` with specified index

```
var td = $("#myTable").find('tr:eq('+index1+')').find('td:eq('+index2+')');
var data = $(td).text();// you can use .html() if you need html inside td
```

Comment: Thnx just the thing i wanted :)

Comment: if it's a textbox in the td; what approach to take? I just added a textbox in one of the td for inline editing and the var data is coming with blank.

Comment: to get text box value use this `var data = $(td).find('input[type=text]').val();`

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
$(function(){
        $('input').click(function()
        { 
         var t= $(this).attr('class'); 


         var text= $('.time'+t).text(); 
            alert(text);                  



        });
            $('td').click(function()
        {  
           var index = this.cellIndex;   


   alert($('tr:first').find('td').eq(index).text());    
    });                             
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oL4pfgda/

Answer (score 1):

It will iterate your table cells and print the values-

```
$("#myTable>tr>td").each(function () {
        var cell_value = $(this).html();
        alert(cell_value);
})
```